# Recursive expression for multiply multiple columns by same column in table

Tags: powerquery, m

I have a table - each row has columns for percentages of different categories plus a column for total value, and I want to calculate the value for each category by multiplying the total value by each category percentage.

I have a table, and, for each of the other columns (`Market Cap.Large`, `Market Cap.Medium` etc. - all except `Symbol`) I want to multiply it by the `Current Value` column. I can do it manually and add a column for each (the `#"Added Custom"` line below), but the number of columns may increase and the titles may change, so I don't want to have to input a custom column for each.

Is there a recursive expression to create a new column for each of the existing ones, and multiply it by `Current Value` - I'm guessing it would involve creating a parameter for the column name, but I'm not knowledgeable enough on how to do it.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n77XV.png)

```
let
    Source = #"Portfolio %",
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Symbol"},#"Current Output Aggregated",{"Symbol"},"Current Output Aggregated",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded Current Output Aggregated" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Current Output Aggregated", {"Current Value"}, {"Current Value"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Current Output Aggregated", "Market Cap.Giant Value", each [Market Cap.Giant]*[Current Value])
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, written on phone, but I think what you want to do is:

1. Create a `List` of columns that you want to multiply by `Current Value` column (all columns except: `Symbol`, `Current Value`).
2. Loop over this newly created `List` using `List.Accumulate` and, in doing so, add a column for each column in the list (by calling `Table.AddColumn` during each loop iteration).

So, something like the `M` code below (copy-paste the below to `Advanced Editor` if necessary):

```
let
    Source = #"Portfolio %",
    mergedQueries = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Symbol"},#"Current Output Aggregated",{"Symbol"},"Current Output Aggregated",JoinKind.Inner),
    expandedNested = Table.ExpandTableColumn(mergedQueries, "Current Output Aggregated", {"Current Value"}, {"Current Value"}),
    allHeaders = Table.ColumnNames(expandedNested),
    headersToLoopOver = List.RemoveItems(allHeaders, {"Symbol", "Current Value"})
    loopOverList = List.Accumulate(headersToLoopOver, expandedNested, (tableState, currentColumn) =>
        Table.AddColumn(tableState, currentColumn & " Value", each Record.Field(_, currentColumn) * [Current Value], type number)
    )
in
    loopOverList
```

Am not sure if I got the`Record.Field` bit right (in the loop) and I don't have access to a machine to test, but it should be easy for you to check if the output is what you expect.